# Streamwriter was not writeable (Xamarin Android)

Tags: xamarin

When I want to write in my asset I´m getting a

System.ArgumentException: Stream was not writable.

I don´t have the problem when  I am using the Streamreader

```
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(assets.Open("lists.csv")))
  {
    foreach (Shoppinglist shp in Listen)
    {
      if (shp.Name != shoplist.Name)
      {
        sw.WriteLine(shp.Name);
        foreach (Product prod in shp.Products)
        {
          sw.WriteLine(prod.Name + ";" + prod.Category + ";" + prod.Pos_x + ";" + prod.Pos_y);
        }
      }
    }

    sw.WriteLine(shoplist.Name);
    foreach (Product prod in shoplist.Products)
    {
      sw.WriteLine(prod.Name + ";" + prod.Category + ";" + prod.Pos_x + ";" + prod.Pos_y);
    }
  }
```

Maybe I should close the asset in other activitys but there is no function for this, otherwise i don´t know how to solve the exception. Opening is alright.

Comment: what is 'assets'?

Comment: Is list.csv an embedded resource?

Comment: its in the assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Assets and other elements that are packaged as part of the Android APK (and the iOS ipa) are read-only and NOT writable.  The packages are signed as part of the distribution process - writing to them at runtime would break the signature.